# Do I need a float or a align or what?

Tags: html, css

This is probably a really simple one. To align the links to the right on the header and the footer should I be using a right align, or a float, or what? I tried "right: 0;" but it moved it all the way to the right of the page rather than to the right of the inner content window.

This is the code I'm working from:
http://jsfiddle.net/HMsKa/76/

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

`right:0` to `#header ul`

`text-align:right` to `#footer`

`position:relative` to `#header_content`

**Demo http://jsfiddle.net/HMsKa/86/**

Answer (score 2):

Do this write this css  [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/HMsKa/84/)

```
#header_content {
position: relative;
}
#header ul {
right: 0;
}
#footer_content {
position: relative;
}
#footer ul {
right: 0;
}
```

[Live demo][1]******

Answer (score 1):

You could use `position:relative` on the parent 'inner content window' and then `position:absolute;right:0;` on the thing within it which you want bound to the side of *that* container. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/HMsKa/76/

You could of course stretch the element the width of its parent and use text-align; not always practical.

Stay away from frivolous floats if possible.

Answer (score 1):

It's best not to mix absolute positioning with floats, try adding `left: 600px;` to your `ul` selector.

Float:right on the ul would work if your whole page was floated